# Predefined variables for YAMl pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to know if there is a way to get predefined variables like releaseID, releaseDefinition as it was in Classical pipeline in Azure Devops. I couldn't find if I have some way of calling these variables in YAML. Please confirm even if its not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables available to a YAML pipeline are documented at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml .

`releaseId` and `releaseDefinition` are not really things in this universe because builds and releases aren't two different KINDS of things with YAML. Rather, they are both just pipelines, and you can either keep them separate (different YAML for build and release) or combined (multi-stage pipeline).

With that in mind, the linked doc includes a number of variables related to the pipeline in question, like `System.DefinitionID`. `System.JobName`, `Environment.ID`, etc.

If you want to see what's available to you, queue up a run of your pipeline with System.Debug set to true.